# why doesn't my code work with older access drivers?

Tags: c++, sql, c, ms-access-2007

```
// SQLTables.cpp
// compile with: user32.lib odbc32.lib
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// simple helper functions
int MySQLSuccess(SQLRETURN rc) {
   return (rc == SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO);
}

struct DataBinding {
   SQLSMALLINT TargetType;
   SQLPOINTER TargetValuePtr;
   SQLINTEGER BufferLength;
   SQLLEN StrLen_or_Ind;
};

void printCatalog(const struct DataBinding* catalogResult, int numCols) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
       if (catalogResult[i].StrLen_or_Ind != SQL_NULL_DATA) 
          printf("Catalog Name(%d) = %s \t", i + 1, (char *)catalogResult[i].TargetValuePtr);
    printf("\n");
}

// remember to disconnect and free memory, and free statements and handles
int main() {
   int bufferSize = 1024, i, numCols = 18;
   struct DataBinding* catalogResult = (struct DataBinding*) malloc( numCols * sizeof(struct DataBinding) );
   wchar_t* dbName = (wchar_t *)malloc( sizeof(wchar_t)*bufferSize );
   wchar_t* userName = (wchar_t *)malloc( sizeof(wchar_t)*bufferSize );

   // declare and initialize the environment, connection, statement handles
   SQLHENV henv = NULL;   // Environment   
   SQLHDBC hdbc = NULL;   // Connection handle
   SQLHSTMT hstmt = NULL;   // Statement handle

   SQLRETURN retCode;
   HWND desktopHandle = GetDesktopWindow();   // desktop's window handle
   SQLWCHAR connStrbuffer[1024];
   SQLSMALLINT connStrBufferLen;

   retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
   retCode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, -6);
   retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
   //retCode = SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)10, 0);
   //retCode = SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc,fOption,(SQLPOINTER)(size_t)param,0);
   //retCode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, desktopHandle, (SQLCHAR*)"DSN=footballDB1;UID=\"\";PWD=\"\"", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)connStrbuffer, 1024 + 1, &connStrBufferLen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
   retCode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, desktopHandle, (SQLCHAR*)"DSN=footballDB;UID=\"\";PWD=\"\"", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)connStrbuffer, 1024 + 1, &connStrBufferLen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
   retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
   retCode = SQLGetInfo(hdbc, SQL_DBMS_NAME , dbName, (SQLSMALLINT)bufferSize, (SQLSMALLINT *)&bufferSize);
   printf("%s\n", dbName);
   retCode = SQLGetInfo(hdbc, SQL_USER_NAME, userName, (SQLSMALLINT)bufferSize, (SQLSMALLINT *)&bufferSize);

   bufferSize = 1024;

   // allocate memory for the binding
   // free this memory when done
   for ( i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++ ) {
      catalogResult[i].TargetType = SQL_C_CHAR;
      catalogResult[i].BufferLength = (bufferSize + 1);
      catalogResult[i].TargetValuePtr = malloc( sizeof(unsigned char)*catalogResult[i].BufferLength );
   }

   // setup the binding (can be used even if the statement is closed by closeStatementHandle)
   for ( i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++ )
      retCode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, (SQLUSMALLINT)i + 1, catalogResult[i].TargetType, catalogResult[i].TargetValuePtr, catalogResult[i].BufferLength, &(catalogResult[i].StrLen_or_Ind));

   // all catalogs query
   printf( "A list of names of all catalogs\n" );
   //retCode = SQLTables( hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"%", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, SQL_NTS );   
   retCode = SQLTables( hstmt, (unsigned char*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (unsigned char*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (unsigned char*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (unsigned char*)"'VIEW','TABLE'", SQL_NTS );
   //retCode = SQLTables( hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, 0, (SQLCHAR*)"schema1", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"'VIEW','TABLE'", SQL_NTS );
   //retCode = SQLTables( hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"%", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"test", SQL_NTS);
   //retCode = SQLColumns(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, 0, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"test", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, 0);
   //retCode = SQLColumns(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, 0, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"CLAIMS_HISTORY_1", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, 0);
   printf( "retCode = %d:%d\n", retCode, SQL_SUCCESS);   
   for ( retCode = SQLFetch(hstmt) ;  MySQLSuccess(retCode) ; retCode = SQLFetch(hstmt) )
      printCatalog( catalogResult, numCols );
   getchar();
}
```

This piece of code is supposed to return the table names in a database and works for access databases saved with *.accdb (ie. the Microsoft Driver) extensions, which i am guessing is one of the latest drivers but i am not able to figure out why it does not work with the Driver do Microsoft Access ( *.mdb). can anyone tell me as to why this is happening?

this is a sample output when a DSN is created with the latest driver.

```
ACCESS
A list of names of all catalogs
retCode = 0:0
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\New folder (4)\football club db2.acc
db      Catalog Name(3) = db_clubs      Catalog Name(4) = TABLE         Catalog
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\New folder (4)\football club db2.acc
db      Catalog Name(3) = db_items      Catalog Name(4) = TABLE         Catalog
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\New folder (4)\football club db2.acc
db      Catalog Name(3) = db_REGION     Catalog Name(4) = TABLE         Catalog
```

and this is a sample output when i create a DSN with the earlier drivers

```
ACCESS
A list of names of all catalogs
retCode = 0:0
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =      Catalog Name(6) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =      Catalog Name(6) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =      Catalog Name(6) =
```

Comment: Where do you get which error?

Comment: i don't get an error.

Comment: Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =      Catalog Name(6) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =      Catalog Name(6) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =      Catalog Name(6) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\football club db    Catalog Name(3)

Comment: that is a sample output from the code when i run it with the older drivers

Comment: Please add updates/addtions to your question to the question itself. You comment is more or less unreadable. Thank you.

Comment: Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\New folder (4)\football club db2.acc
db      Catalog Name(3) = db_clubs      Catalog Name(4) = TABLE         Catalog
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\New folder (4)\football club db2.acc
db      Catalog Name(3) = db_items      Catalog Name(4) = TABLE         Catalog
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■     Catalog Name(18) =
Catalog Name(1) = C:\Users\akisho02\Desktop\New folder (4)\football club db2.acc
db      Catalog Name(3) = db_REGION     Catalog Name(4) = TABLE         Catalog
≡¡║ε½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■

Comment: that is a sample output from the latest driver

Comment: do you notice the table names that are printed in the latter piece of output? db_items,db_REGION,db_clubs etc.

Comment: i have updated my question with the output, do you notice the table names? it comes as Catalog Name(3) = db_clubs etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I saw with microsoft access driviers. I would suggest you use the latest version that the system offers in while setting up your database connection.